# how to migrate extensions to magento 2?

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, migrate

I just Started working with magento 2, right now I installed and migrated customers and orders. and I’m trying to migrate some extensions data like Amasty ShopBy. I Installed it in my magento 2 after checking and comparing the tables in both databases they look the same . I’m asking what is the best practice to migrate the data to magento 2?

Comment: better you install all required extension first and then start migration. so all required tables will be exist and you can add extension tables also in migration script.

Comment: I already migrated customers and orders, is there a way to migrate just extension tables ?

Comment: just export tables and import, if you have already migrate then you should not migrate again

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you won't be able to migrate the extensions, since M2 is completely different from M1. I'd suggest you make a list of all the useful extensions and look for the M2 alternatives to install on your new store. Guess, that's the only way out for you.

Comment: Hi sarah! Thank you for your reply. This is exactly what I did I installed the alternatives M2 extension., I'm now trying to migrate the data of these extensions from M1 to M2 and since the tables are now identical, in which direction you suggest me to go ?